# Swift upload UIImage with multipart form without parameters

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire, combine

Server I work with accepts:

```
  curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://some.url' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'data=@your-image.jpg;type=image/jpeg'
```

All I can find is examples with parameters. I have tried everything, alamofire and standard url sessions

Comment: The process is the same. Just don’t add any parameters to the payload. You can comment out the parameters code if it bothers you. E.g., if using Alamofire, just don’t supply any parameters. It’s optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason only Alamofire worked this is final method I've used.

```
AF.upload(
              multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                  multipartFormData.append(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)!, withName: UUID().uuidString, fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
          },
              to: "https://someurl.com", method: .post , headers: headers)
            .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
                //Current upload progress of file
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                    })
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { data in
                //Do what ever you want to do with response
                print(data)
                    })
```